# In a chained promise, why is the second promise executing before the first promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am using this authorization flow to get an access token for the Spotify API. The first promise in this set of chained promise sets the `access_token`, unless there is an error, where it logs the error to the console. The second promise simply prints out the recently set access token. I thought that this code would prevent the code inside the second `.then()` from executing until after the first promise gets resolved.

```
console.log("PRE ACCESS TOKEN: " + spotifyApi.getAccessToken())

spotifyApi.clientCredentialsGrant().then(
  function(data) {
    console.log("The access token expires in " + data.body["expires_in"]);
    console.log("The access token is " + data.body["access_token"]);

    // Save the access token so that it's used in future calls
    spotifyApi.setAccessToken(data.body["access_token"]);
  },

  function(err) {
    console.log(
      "Something went wrong when retrieving an access token",
      err.message
    );
  }
).then( 
    console.log("POST ACCESS TOKEN: " + spotifyApi.getAccessToken())
);
```

But I am getting this output:

```
PRE ACCESS TOKEN: undefined
POST ACCESS TOKEN: undefined
```

Which means that the second promise, within the second `.then()`, is executing before the first promise. Why is this happening? I think I probably have a fundamental misunderstanding of how promises in Javascript work, but I'm not sure about exactly what I don't understand.

Comment: afaik you need to return something in the first then statement, to chain another then or you can make the first then function an async one, so that it returns a promise and later on once it's resolved, it'll call the second then function.

Comment: @DakshMiglani Yep, returning something from the first then statement works. But wdym by making the first function async? How would I do that?

Comment: an async function returns a promise, so you just add the `async` keyword before `function` kinda like this: `async function gg() { do_something_here; }`. when you call this function, it'll return a promise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line is not chaining a promise

```
.then( 
    console.log("POST ACCESS TOKEN: " + spotifyApi.getAccessToken())
);
```

You pass a function to a promise so the promise can call the function when it completes.

Pass a function and it should start working

```
.then(function() { 
    console.log("POST ACCESS TOKEN: " + spotifyApi.getAccessToken())
});
```

Comment: thanks! that makes sense. clearly I need to do more than just skim through the promise docs.